# Compute $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \arctan \frac{x} {1+k(k+1)x^2}$, $x>0$

Tags: limits

I tried using the squeeze theorem, but I had no luck. Then I thought that maybe the sum is telescoping, but also I couldn't see any pattern.

Comment: is that arctan$(x) \cdot$ that fraction or arctan of the fraction?

Comment: *Hint:* $x=(k+1)x-kx$.

Comment: arctan of that fraction

Comment: @user10354138 could you develop your hint please?

Comment: have you tried the arctan addition formula?

Comment: I have and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Viktor Gomblik says that you can replace your big general term $\mathrm{atan}(....)$  by $\mathrm{atan}(...)-\mathrm{atan}(...)$. In this way you get a telescopic series. You should verify that you finaly obtain a result of the form $\pi/2$ minus some simple function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the given expression as follows:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\sum_{k=1}^n$ $\tan^{-1} (\frac{x}{1+k(k+1)x^2})$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\sum_{k=1}^n$ $ \tan^{-1}( \frac{(k+1)x - kx}{1+k(k+1)x^2})$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\sum_{k=1}^n$ $(\tan^{-1} ((k+1)x) - \tan^{-1}(kx))$

Applying the limit and by telescopic sum,

$\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\sum_{k=1}^n$ $(\tan^{-1} ((k+1)x) - \tan^{-1}(kx))$

$=\tan^{-1}\infty - \tan^{-1} x$

$= \frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}x$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula
\begin{equation}
\arctan{u}+\arctan{v}=\arctan{\frac{u+v}{1-u v}}
\end{equation}
which is valid for $u v <1$. Now consider the sum. For $k=1$ you have
\begin{equation}
\arctan{\frac{x}{1+2 x^2}}
\end{equation}
and for $k=2$
\begin{equation}
\arctan{\frac{x}{1+6 x^2}}
\end{equation}
If you apply the formula above to the first two term you get:
\begin{equation}
\arctan{\frac{x}{1+2 x^2}}+\arctan{\frac{x}{1+6 x^2}}=\arctan{\frac{2x}{1+3 x²}}
\end{equation}
 You can repeat the same computation for the term obtained using $k=3$ and $k=4$ and so on and find the expression:
\begin{equation}
\arctan{\frac{2x}{1+x²(2 m+1)(2m-1)}}
\end{equation}
where the index $m$ runs from 1 to N/2. This procedure can be repeated again and again. For instance the $\arctan{\frac{2x}{1+3 x²}}$ can be added to the sum of the terms obtained by using $k=3$ and $k=4$ and the sum can be written as 
\begin{equation}
\arctan{\frac{4x}{1+x²(4w-31)(4w+1)}}
\end{equation}
where the index $w$ runs from 1 to N/4. By applying the formula of the sum of the two arctan it is possible to compute:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \arctan \frac{x} {1+k(k+1)x^2}=\frac{2 x n}{1+x²(2 n +1)}
\end{equation}
So that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \arctan \frac{x} {1+k(k+1)x^2}=arccot(x)
\end{equation} 
please note that $arccot(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan{x}$.