# How do I solve this Sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Calculate the following sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan \left( \frac{x}{1+n(n-1) x^2} \right)$$

Using that:

$$\arctan a-\arctan b=\arctan \left( \frac{a-b}{1+a b} \right)$$

Comment: What have you tried? And where does this problem come from? Finally, what is $\text{arctg}$?

Comment: I’d make a guess that a = nx and b = (n-1)x.

Comment: @KamalSaleh "arctg" is the Spanish printing of "arctan." I've edited to reflect this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3003656/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Carctan%20%5Cleft(%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B1%2Bn(n-1)%20x%5E2%7D%20%5Cright)%24)

Comment: Thatnk you @MartinR, I did not see that one

Answer (score 1):

Taking $a=nx$ and $b=(n-1)x$, and using the property provided:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \operatorname{arctan} \frac{x}{1+n(n-1) x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \operatorname{arctan}nx-\operatorname{arctan}(n-1)x\right)
$$
Then, by being a telescopic sum:
$$S_n=\operatorname{arctan}nx$$
So the sum is the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\operatorname{arctan}nx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: More precisely, the limit should be $\frac \pi 2 \text{sign}(x)$.